# Pourquoi la graphie ancienne "joye" est devenue "joie" en français moderne ?

Tags: orthographe, histoire, ancien-français

Bonjour,

Y a-t-il une raison pour le changement de la graphie *jo**y**e* en ancien français à la graphie *jo**i**e* en français moderne ?

Tout de même, pourquoi on écrit aujourd'hui *jo**y**eux* et non *jo**i**eux* ?

Comment: Soie - soyeux / *moieus* - moyeu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour commencer nous allons faire un point sur l'histoire de la langue pour montrer que la graphie *joie* est plus ancienne que celle de *joye* et voir comment l'orthographe a évolué de l'ancien français à la langue actuelle. Ensuite nous intéresserons à l'adjectif *joyeux* et essaierons de faire le lien entre graphie et prononciation.

La **graphie** *joie* existait en [ancien français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancien_fran%C3%A7ais). On la trouve dans la [Chanson de Roland](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/glossaire-chanson-de-roland/joie), dans le [Roman de la Rose](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/glossaire-roman-de-la-rose/joie), où sont présentes les graphies *joianz* et *joieus* pour *joyeux*.
De même roi était écrit *roi* et on trouve [roion](http://micmap.org/dicfro/next/glossaire-roman-de-renart-fhs/530/roi) (*Roman de Renart*) et [roiaume](http://micmap.org/dicfro/next/glossaire-roman-de-tristan/227/roiaume) (*Le roman de Tristan*) pour *royaume*, et on pourra facilement trouver d'autres exemples en ligne, comme ce poème d'Eustache Deschamps (XIV<sup>e</sup> siècle)

> Nulz ne puet estre parfait
> Ne mener joieuse vie
> S’amour joieux ne le fait,
> Qui soustient chevalerie.

Dans *Histoire d'une langue, le français*<sup>1</sup> [Marcel Cohen](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcel_Cohen), dans le chapitre sur l'orthographe du [moyen français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyen_fran%C3%A7ais),  mentionne « l’orthographe pour l'esprit » et « l'orthographe pour l’œil » qui était à la fois le fait des copistes et des débuts de l'imprimerie qui vit le jour en Europe au XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle. « L'orthographe pour l’œil » sont des « combinaisons de caractères qui flattaient un certain goût ornemental du temps », ainsi « *y* au lieu de *i* à la fin des mots » est qualifié de « variante[ ] ornementale[ ] ».

Bien que le [DMF](http://zeus.atilf.fr/dmf/) n'ait pas d'entrées pour ces mots, on trouve la première trace de la graphie *oy* (*roy*, *loy*, *joye*) en remplacement de *oi* dans le [dictionnaire de Cotgrave](http://micmap.org/dicfro/introduction/cotgrave) (1611). Cotgrave mentionne aussi *joyeux*, *royal*, *loyal* et autres composés.

Dans son chapitre sur l'orthographe du français moderne Marcel Cohen continue : « ...le public des gens instruits du XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle ne supportait plus l'orthographe du 17<sup>e</sup> siècle. L'Académie elle-même, entraînée par l'abbé d'Olivet a donné satisfaction dans son dictionnaire de 1740 à un puissant mouvement d'opinion (...) on a aussi éliminé *y* pour *i* à la fin des mots (*roy, roi*) ; ...  »

Effectivement si on consulte les différentes éditions du [*Dictionnaire de l'Académie*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/presentation.html#AideSommaire) on constate que les éditions de 1694 et 1718 donne la graphie *oy*, et c'est dans celle de 1740 qu'apparait pour la première fois la graphie *oi*. La graphie des dérivés de ces mots en *oy/oi* s'écrit avec *y* depuis la première édition du dictionnaire en 1694.

La forme actuelle de l'adjectif ***joyeux*** ne vient ni du nom  *joie* ni de sa forme *joy* utilisée en moyen français mais directement de l'adjectif de l'ancien français *joieux*. Le *Dictionnaire historique en langue française*<sup>2</sup> indique que :

> *joyeux* est la réfection<sup>3</sup> (v. 1375) de *joieux*, lui même aboutissement de *goiuse* (1050), joiuse (1080, le nom de l'épée de Charlemagne), *joose* (fin du XII<sup>e</sup> siècle).

De même, *loyal* est issu de l'adjectif *leial* (1080) et *royal* de *roial* (v. 1188).

Pour ce qui est de la **prononciation** nous devons nous intéresser au couple *oi*. La prononciation est le point le plus difficile à établir car les linguistes ne peuvent travailler qu'à partir de reconstructions<sup>4</sup>. Marcel Cohen traite de l'évolution de la prononciation dans son Histoire du français mais je trouve plus facile ici de me référer à [Jacques Leclerc](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Leclerc_(linguiste)) :

> Au cours des XIII<sup>e</sup> et XIV<sup>e</sup> siècles, l'ancien français continuera d'évoluer. Ainsi, la graphie *oi* est passée de la prononciation en [oi] comme dans boy à [oé], puis [oè] et finalement [wè]: des mots comme *roi, moi, loi, toi*, etc., étaient donc prononcés [rwè], [mwè], [lwè], [twè], etc. La prononciation en [wa] était déjà attestée au XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle, mais elle n'était pas généralisée. Certains critiquaient cette prononciation en [wa], car elle était surtout employée par les classes modestes ; elle triomphera à la Révolution française<sup>5</sup>.

On pourra voir aussi [pages 353-354](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k50766v/f358.item) de *La grammaire française et les grammairiens du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle* par Ch.-L. Livet qui cite [Henri Estienne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Estienne) sur la prononciation de *y*.

Il semble donc que la prononciation [ʒwajø] soit antérieure à la graphie *joyeux*.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Marcel Cohen, Histoire d’une langue : le français (des lointaines origines à nos jours)*, Éditions sociales , 1973.

<sup>2</sup> *Dictionnaire historique en langue française*, sld Alain Rey, éditions le Robert, 1992.

<sup>3</sup> « Reformation à partir d’un modèle préexistant. Opération qui consiste à modifier une forme populaire due à l'évolution normale d'un mot, en la transformant pour la rapprocher de son étymon » (définition du [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9fection))

<sup>4</sup> « Il est difficile de se faire une idée de ce qu'était, au XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle, la prononciation de l'ancien français. » (Jacques Leclerc).</sup> 
<sup><sup>5</sup> LECLERC, Jacques. « La période féodale : l'ancien français » dans *L’aménagement linguistique dans le monde*, Québec, CEFAN, Université Laval, 17 mars 2015,
[http://www.axl.cefan.ulaval.ca/francophonie/HIST_FR_s3_Ancien-francais.htm], (23 janvier 2022), 124 Ko.</sup>

Comment: Je n'ai pas le droit de dire "merci", mais merci quand même ! Je n'ai pas compris ce passage : "joyeux est la réfection3 (v. 1375) de joieux." Que signifie "réfection" ? J'ai lu la note, mais je n'arrive pas à comprendre le y dans les dérivés.

Comment: @ovide C'est une terme employé en linguistique. Est-ce que la [définition du wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9fection) est plus claire : Reformation à partir d’un modèle préexistant. Opération qui consiste à modifier une forme populaire due à l'évolution normale d'un mot, en la transformant pour la rapprocher de son étymon. Si oui, je remplacerai. Je veux aussi ajouter une note sur roy, loy, pour élargir.

Comment: Peut-être que @Eau qui dort fera une réponse, cette personne est très calée en ancien français et histoire de la prononciation. Tu pourras toujours « désaccepter » ma réponse. Je ne suis pas tout à fait dans ma spécialité ici.

Comment: Si je comprends bien, cette réfection signifie (pour simplifier) que *joieux* est passé à *joyeux* pour ressembler à *joy* (cette dernière été changée en *joie* par la suite) c'est bien ça ?

Comment: @XouDo Je ne suis pas spécialiste de phonétique et d'étymologie mais  toutes les sources consultées (certaines accessibles en ligne et je donne les liens) sont claires *joie* est antérieur à *joy*, donc *changée* est inexact (rétablit ?). Pour répondre à ta question je dirais que je comprends ce que dit le DHLF comme disant que *joyeux* a été construit directement à partir de *joieux* qui se prononçait [ʒwajø] (voir Leclerc et Estienne). « Lignées » différentes : le DHLF a des entrées différentes pour *joie* et pour *joyeux*, alors que les dérivés sont normalement sous une même entrée.

Comment: @None Merci pour cette précision. Malheureusement "construit directement à partir de joieux" n'explique pas vraiment ce choix de passer à *y* au lieu de *i*. Est-ce par une volonté de mieux décrire la prononciation "joi-yeu" et non "joi-eu" ? Je vais essayer d'explorer un peu de ce côté.

Comment: @XouDo Pour « ce choix de passer à y au lieu de i » voir ce que dit Marcel Cohen (et on le trouve aussi dans Ch.-L. Livet, c'est quelque chose de bien répertorié). C'est que M. Cohen appelle « l'orthographe pour l’œil ». L'histoire de la prononciation du y, c'est toute une épopée !

Comment: https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k50766v : *"Henri Estienne, (...) ajoute que l’y entre deux voyelles a le son de deux ii dont le premier appartiendrait à la syllabe précédente, le second à la syllabe suivante (...) la forme de l’y s’expliquerait par cet emploi : il remplace deux i précisément parceque, anciennement, on écrivait deux i dont le second était plus allongé, ij : moijen, loijal."* Hypothèse séduisante (ij ressemble à y), mais qui semble démentie par le fait qu’on ne trouve aucune occurrence des graphies *moiien/moijen* ou *loiial/loijal* dans la littérature.

Comment: @XouDo Oui, je sais cet extrait **est inclus** dans le passage auquel je renvoie dans ma réponse sur la prononciation du y. Et je te le rappelle dans mon commentaire précédent....

Comment: Oui bien sûr vous avez mentionné les pages, mais je me permet de citer en particulier un passage amenant des élément pour cette question de *i* vs *y*.

Comment: @XouDo Vu que c'est exactement la même chose je ne vois vraiment pas ce qui se cache derrière ta démarche. Bon mieux vaut ça que reprendre en réponse des réponses déjà faites, c'est vrai. Ici ce n'est qu'un commentaire.

Comment: Quel est le problème, ce n'était pas cité, ça correspond à la question...?

Comment: @XouDo  Oui, je vois un problème vu que c'est moi qui cite le passage, il suffit de cliquer sur le lien pour le lire. J'avais même déjà donné toutes les pages (sauf celle de Leclerc) dans les commentaires que j'ai compilés pour rédiger la réponse. Commentaires effacés puisque j'ai fait une réponse quelques jours après, à ce moment là tant que c'était des commentaires si quelqu'un avait voulu reprendre pour faire une réponse il aurait pu. Je comprends mieux tes premiers commentaires, en fait tu n'avais pas lu ma réponse.

Comment: Non, non j'avais bien lu ta réponse (je n'ai pas ouvert chaque lien... une réponse doit se suffire à elle-même!) et je maintiens mes remarques précédente. Vexez-vous si ça vous chante!

Comment: @x Je ne suis pas vexé (pas de quoi) je trouve la démarche extrêmement malhonnête. Vu que tu cites exactement ce qu'il y a derrière le lien c'est bien que tu as cliqué dessus. Je reconnais que c'est quand même déjà mieux que la fois où j'avais fait remarquer à quelqu'un en quoi sa réponse était fausse, et qu'il l'a rectifiée... en reprenant la mienne. Je laisse tous mes commentaires pour qu'on ne pense pas que j'ai fait la même chose ici. Avec les dates et heures on peut voir qui a recopié sur qui.

Answer (score 1):

Aujourd'hui, on écrit *joie, joyeux* et non *joye, joieux* parce qu'on dit /⁠ʒwa⁠/, /⁠ʒwajø⁠/ et non /⁠ʒwaj⁠/, /⁠ʒwaø⁠/. En règle générale, on écrit "oy" pour /⁠waj⁠/ et "oi" pour /⁠wa⁠/. De la même façon, on écrit "ay" pour /⁠ɛj⁠/ (ou /⁠ej⁠/) et "ai" pour /⁠ɛ⁠/ ou /⁠e⁠/.

En moyen français, il était fréquent d'écrire "y" au lieu de "i" à la fin d'un mot ou à côté d'une autre voyelle.

Je ne sais pas quand la règle moderne a été créé, mais l'outil [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=celuy%2Ccelui%2Cioye%2Cjoie&year_start=1500&year_end=1800&corpus=30&smoothing=3) montre plus des exemples de "celuy" et "ioye"  que de "celui" et "joie" jusqu'au XVIIe siècle:

[image]

Dans une discussion Reddit (en anglais) "[When was the Middle French form "luy" changed to its modern equivalent "lui"?](https://www.reddit.com/r/French/comments/jhevbv/when_was_the_middle_french_form_luy_changed_to/)", WilcoAppetizer indique qu'on trouve les formes "roi" et "jeudi" dans les dictionnaires pour "roy" et "jeudy" depuis 1740.

Comment: Ceci ne répond pas à la question « pourquoi on écrit aujourd'hui joyeux et non joieux » !

Comment: @None Pourquoi "Parce que on dit /ʒwajø/ et /ʒwa/" n'est pas une réponse?

Comment: @Gae.S. Je comprends pas la question comme demandant  pourquoi l'adjectif s'écrit avec un *y* alors que le substantif est *joie*. Il n'est pas question de prononciation pour moi. Je comprends la question comme se plaçant dans une perspective historique : comment en est-on arrivé là ?

Comment: Le y à la fin des mots était une « orthographe pour l’œil : lettres qui ne se font point entendre, mais combinaisons (...) variantes ornementales (...) à la fin de certains mots (...) y au lieu de i », le i a été rétabli au 18e s (M. Cohen). J'ai lu des détails dans le livre de C. L. Livet (il me semble que c'est l'Ac. Français qui a décidé de  rétablir le i ), mais nous n'avons  toujours pas la réponse à la question : pourquoi les dérivés se sont-ils faits à partir de la terminaison Y ? Quelle est l'évolution ?